# base64 encoded PNG to Blob

Tags: blob, dart

I am fiddling around with creating a Blob out of a base64 encoded PNG...

```dart
  final FormData formData = new FormData();
  final String base64Image = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K<reduced the data.....>gg==";

  final Blob blob = new Blob([base64Image],"image/png");

  formData.append('file', blob, "android.png");

  req.send(formData);
```

I don't know what I a doing wrong but the contents of blob is something but not the png I would like it to be.

thx in advance...

[**Update**]

```dart
  final FormData formData = new FormData();
  final String base64Image = "iVBORw0KGgo<...reduce data...>kJggg==";

  // BTW: I used the Base64 from dart-sdk/io/base64.dart
  final List<int> intList = Base64.decode(base64Image);
  final Int8Array int8array = new Int8Array.fromList(intList);
  final String atobString = window.atob(base64Image);

  // Does not work
  // final Blob blob = new Blob([atobString]);

  // The same...
  // final Blob blob = new Blob([int8array]);

  formData.append('file', blob, "android.png");
  //formData.append('new-filename', "icon-share.png");

  req.send(formData);
```

I think the number of bytes generated by Base64.decode are OK. The filesize was 1003 bytes and decoding also produces 1003 bytes.

[**Update 2**]
Here is the source I am talking about:
https://github.com/MikeMitterer/AndroidIconGenerator.DART/blob/master/test/src/restserver.dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, here is the answer to my own question:

```dart
import 'dart:convert'
...

test(' -> Upload File to REST-Server', () {

  final HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

  loadEnd(HttpRequest request) {
    if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE) {

      switch(request.status) {

        case HttpStatus.HTTP_200_OK:
          expect(response['path'].endsWith("android.png"),true);
          
          break;

        case HttpStatus.HTTP_0_COMMUNICATION_FAILED:
          expect(request.status,HttpStatus.HTTP_200_OK);
          break;

        default:
          expect(request.status,HttpStatus.HTTP_200_OK);
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  req.open("POST", uriprovider.forUpload().toString());
  
  // REST returns JSON Data
  req.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

  req.onLoadEnd.listen(expectAsync1((ProgressEvent e) => loadEnd(req)));
  
  final FormData formData = new FormData();
  
  final String base64Image = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG<code reduce for sample>RU5ErkJggg==";
  final String raw = "iVBORw0KG<code reduce for sample>RU5ErkJggg==";
  final String contenttype = "image/png";
  
  // Base64 is a modified version of dart-sdk/lib/io/base64.dart
  final List<int> intList = BASE64.decode(raw);
  final Int8Array int8array = new Int8Array.fromList(intList);

  // Converting to Uint8Array brought the solution!
  final Uint8Array uint8array = new Uint8Array.fromList(int8array);
  
  // does not work!
  //var binary = window.atob(raw);
  
  final Blob blob = new Blob([uint8array]);
  
  formData.append('file', blob, "android.png");

  req.send(formData);
  
});
```

Thanks to everyone pushing me in the right direction!

Comment: where are we using the `int8array` in the code? is the line `final Uint8Array uint8array = new Uint8Array(intList.length);` incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Need **decode base64** (i.e. atob) url, before you encode to Blob. It's easy! Try it!

Comment: Hmmm, it seems not to be so easy...

I tried it with atob and also with Base64.decode(base64Image);
(please refere to my updated question...) Nothing helps...

Comment: Remove "data:image/png;base64,".

Comment: I tried it from the beginning with and without data:image... doesn't work either.